# relative scaled navigationbar with moving box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a nice looking navigation(relative scale) with a box, that moves smooth between the navigation points. So if I select a navigation point the box moves smooth to the selected entry point. But I don`t know how to do that.

here is a example for the smooth animation:

```js
var boxOne = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0],
    $boxTwo = $('.box:eq(1)');

document.getElementsByClassName('toggleButton')[0].onclick = function() {
  if(this.innerHTML === 'Play') 
  { 
    this.innerHTML = 'Pause';
    boxOne.classList.add('horizTranslate');
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'Play';
    var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(boxOne),
        marginLeft = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('margin-left');
    boxOne.style.marginLeft = marginLeft;
    boxOne.classList.remove('horizTranslate');    
  }  
}
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.box.horizTranslate {
  -webkit-transition: 3s;
  -moz-transition: 3s;
  -ms-transition: 3s;
  -o-transition: 3s;
  transition: 3s;
  margin-left: 50% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Pausing Transitions</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <h3>Example</h3>
<div class='box'></div> 
<button class='toggleButton' value='play'>Play</button>

  <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently my Code looks like this:

```css
@font-face { 
font-family: "FireSans"; 
src: url("../fonts/FiraSans-Light.ttf"); 
}

body{

 background-color: green;

}

#header{
 
 width: 80%;
 max-width: 1300px;
 min-width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto;

}

#table{

 width: 100%

}

#logo{

 height: 170px;
 
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto; 

}

#menu{

 padding-top: 75px;
 
 color: white;
 font-family: "FireSans";
 font-size: 1.5em;
 
 width: 280px;
 
}

#menutable{

 width: 280px;

}

#test {

 height: 4px;
 width: 85%;
 background-color: rgb(185,224,78);
 margin: auto;

}
```

```html
 <div id="header">
 
 <table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th id="menu" align="right"><table id="menutable"><thead><tr><th id="start">STARTSEITE<div id="test"></th><th id="ende"onmouseover="changeBox()">KANÄLE</th></tr></thead></table></th>
        <th style="width:344px;"><img id="logo" src="./images/logo.jpg"></th>
         <th id="menu" align="left"><table id="menutable"><thead><tr><th>BEWERBEN</th><th>LOGIN</th></tr></thead></table></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>

 </div>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: what exactly do yo mean when you say: f I select a navigation point the box moves smooth to the selected entry point??

Comment: If I hover for example on "Kanäle" the green box moves among the "Kanäle" div.